# utf8::next() of utfcpp - tries to iterate past the end of the string

Tags: c++, utf-8, utfcpp

I'm using UTFCPP to work with UTF-8 encoded strings stored in std::string objetcs.

I want to iterate over the code points. utf8::next()

```
uint32_t next(octet_iterator& it, octet_iterator end);
```

seems the way to do this. Here's a test program to illustrate the use:

```
std::string u8("Hello UTF-8 \u2610\u2193\u2190\u0394 World!\n");
std::cout << u8 << std::endl;
uint32_t cp = 0;
std::string::iterator b = u8.begin();
std::string::iterator e = u8.end();
while (cp = utf8::next(b,e))
    printf("%d, ", cp);
```

This extracts all the characters fine, however, the program throws a NOT_ENOUGH_ROOM exception, which indicates that "**it** gets equal to **end** during the extraction of a code point" just after printing the 10, which is the ASCII newline control character:

```
Hello UTF-8 ☐↓←Δ World!
72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 85, 84, 70, 45, 56, 32, 9744, 8595, 8592, 916, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33, 10,
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'utf8::not_enough_room'
what():  Not enough space
```

Obviously, providing the end iterator seems to be insufficient to keep utf8::next from trying to read over the end of the string.

I'm also confused by the utf8::unchecked::next() function, which does not even take an end iterator. How does this know where to stop? Is catching the exception the *normal* control flow to detect the end of the string?? 
Obviously I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are responsible for checking whether the iterator is equal to end() before calling next(). 
This should work without an exception being thrown:

```
[...]
uint32_t cp = 0;
std::string::iterator b = u8.begin();
std::string::iterator e = u8.end();
while ( b != e ) {
    cp = utf8::next(b,e);
    printf("%d, ", cp);
}
```

Generally, the use of exceptions for control flow is considered to be an anti-pattern.

Comment: excellent. That was of course the obvious thing. The exception is not the normal control flow.